# How to download all files from google bucket directory to local directory using google oauth

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-storage

Is there any way using OAuth to download all content of a google bucket directory to a local directory.

I found two ways using (get request object) from storage API and gsutil. But since API uses direct name downloading I have to first parse all the list of bucket content and then send get request and then download it. I find gsutil more convenient but for this, I have to hard code details for the credential.

Basically, i am developing a client related application where I have to download the big query table data to the client local server
Can anyone help me for this

Comment: Take a look at this. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/gspythonlibrary

Comment: I think in this mode the user will be provided a link and then he will be ask to copy the code

Comment: You can use the blobstore api to upload or download files from your google bucket. See if that helps!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran i need oauth based system to download approx 10-15 Gb of data

Answer (score 0):

Unless your application knows ahead of time the object names that you want to download, you'll need to perform a list followed by GETs for each object.

You can use the [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) client library to do this.  You can configure your client application has the OAuth2 credentials and the library should handle the rest of the necessary authentication for you.  See the documentation [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/google-cloud-auth.html) for the basics of authentication, and [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html for interacting with Google Cloud Storage objects.

Comment: I read the documentation but still I am unable to create explicit credentials object the error is coming

Comment: If you think this is a bug in the library, you can post on their issue tracker.  Otherwise, if you include the error details here, someone may be able to help.